# Library that fetches "critical" machine information for debugging purposes?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

The "critical" machine information will be logged and shall be used for debugging purposes once our software is in the field.

"Critical" information may include data that is "generally" important for debugging the application. It may include:

1. Operating System
2. Windows Updates Installed
3. Hardware information: CPU, RAM, HDD
4. Processes/Services running
5. Current user account

I'm sorry for asking such vague question and I believe that it's fairly trivial to write a custom one using WMI. But, if there's already a library/framework that is designed to do this kind of stuff, it would be great to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I would focus on the logging framework first (e.g. NLog, log4net etc), then retrieving the environment variables second.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, ***pseudocode!***

```
        private StringBuilder GetSystemInformationString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation).GetProperties();
            if (properties != null && properties.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pin in properties)
                {
                    sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(pin.Name + " : " + pin.GetValue(pin, null));
                }
            }

            return sb;

        }
```

for memory can use something like this :

```
(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024).ToString() + " Kb";
```

Regards.